# Spring Session with Redis - NotSerializableException

Tags: spring, session, redis

I need to use `Redis` to store my `HttpSessions`. I am following the instructions provided in this [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/boot-redis.html)

But I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: My project is in this link https://github.com/diogomartinez/PoCRedisSessionConfig

Comment: Problem solved. The problem was that SpringBootApplication, RestController and Scope annotations where all in the same class.